# issue with mysql query, bad coding?

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I am trying to do the following PHP / MySQL query, and it works fine for the first two groups, but for everyone else I am getting a MySQL error, is this written correctly?

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$N = $user->get('name'); 
$username = $user->get('username');
$groups = $user->get('groups');

foreach($groups as $groupName=>$groupId)
{
}

$G=$groupName;

if ($G=="Management Staff")
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead");
elseif ($G=="Website Developers")
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead");
else
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE createdby=$N");
```

When I login as anyone else I get :

`Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\server2go\server2go\htdocs\chandlers\components\com_jumi\views\application\view.html.php(38) : eval()'d code on line 87`

`Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\server2go\server2go\htdocs\chandlers\components\com_jumi\views\application\view.html.php(38) : eval()'d code on line 132`

Comment: Where is the call to `mysql_fetch_object` that the error is referencing?  I don't see a call to `mysql_fetch_object` in your code snippet above.  Does it come after this block on `$result`?  It would appear that `$result` is not being set if that is the case.

Comment: Using PHP variables directly in SQL queries is definitely not good practice, it leaves you open to the possibility of an SQL injection.  Also, the mysql_* functions have fallen out of favour, mysqli or PDO is the preferred method of interfacing with a database these days

Comment: Hi, im just a beginner so not sure on any other way, how could I declare to only load records from a particular user other than declaring their username manually in the sql?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE createdby=$N");
```

is fishy, should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE createdby='$N'");
```

make sure, $N has nothing evil in it.

Comment: thanks, that is working now and only displaying results created by that user how it is supposed to, thanks :-) , I will accept your answer in a moment when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was just a poor copy/paste job by you into stackoverflow but it looks like your curly braces are all out of sorts.  Think you would want something more like this:

```
$username = $user->get('username');
$groups = $user->get('groups');
foreach($groups as $groupName=>$groupId) {
  $G=$groupName;
  if ($G=="Management Staff")
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead");
  elseif ($G=="Website Developers")
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead");
  else
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE     createdby=$N");
}
```

So that your foreach loop actually executes the code below it.  The code you pasted into your question has a for each loop which executes nothing in the loop because it is written like this:

```
foreach($groups as $groupName=>$groupId) {}
```

And then you proceed to try to use one of the variables from the foreach loops outside of the loop:

```
$G=$groupName;
if ($G=="Management Staff")
...
```

Which won't work because the `$groupName` variable will only be set within the scope of the `foreach` loop.